# Empty line in arraylist Java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    protected synchronized static void getRandomProxy(String srcFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
         BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
             reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(srcFile));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                words.add(line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
                k++;
                String[] splitted = words.get(i).split(":");
                String ip = splitted[0];
                String port = splitted[splitted.length - 1];
//                System.out.println(k + " " + ip + " * " + port);
            }
        } catch (IOException iOException) {
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
```

I want to get output printed without empty lines .
These are kind of results am getting Like :

result 1.

result 2.

result 3.

i want output like :

result 1.
result 2.
result 3.

without blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(srcFile));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim(); // remove leading and trailing whitespace
        if (!line.isEmpty() && !line.equals("")) {

            words.add(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.print`. Note that the file contains a newline char at the end of each line.

If srcFile is created with Notepad, try removing first the carriage return char `System.out.print(line.replaceAll("\\r",""))`

Comment: that is printing them on the same line like : result 1.result 2.result 3.

Comment: Also if i sprint out   System.out.print(words.get(1)); am getting nothing but   System.out.print(words.get(0)); and   System.out.print(words.get(2)); am getting results.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the String to the list if it's empty :

```
if(!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
    words.add(line);
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

If you still want to add the blank lines to the list but don't display them, just move the condition :

```
words.add(line);
if(!line.trim().isEmpty())
    System.out.println(line);
```

[Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--)

Comment: try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(srcFile));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                    words.add(line);
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

            } This is still outputing empty lines.

Comment: Don't forget to [trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--).